# C++ Deleting a specfic value in a vector without knowing location

Tags: c++, vector, stack, erase

```
if (find(visitable.begin(), visitable.end(), ourstack.returnTop())) { ... }
```

I want to determine whether the top character in stack `ourstack` can be found in the vector `visitable`. If yes, I want this character to be deleted from `visitable`.

How would I code that? I know vectors use `erase`, but that requires the specific location of that character (which I don't know).

This is for my [maze-path-finding assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763233/algorithm-to-print-to-screen-paths-through-a-text-maze).

Also, my `returnTop` is giving me an error: `class "std.stack<char..." has no member returnTop`. I declared #include  in the top of my program. What's happening here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `std::remove()` to remove by value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385229/c-erase-vector-element-by-value-rather-than-by-position - as for `returnTop` - can you show your class declaration?

Comment: Do you want to remove all instances of that character, or just one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `find`, then you already know the location of the character. `find` returns an iterator to the position where the character is found, or to the value used as end if it cannot find it.

```
vector<?>::const_iterator iter =
    find(visitable.begin(), visitable.end(), ourstack.top());
if( iter != visitable.end() )
{
    visitable.erase( iter );
}
```

As for `stack`, the function you are looking for is `top()`. The standard C++ library does not use camelCased identifiers, that looks more like a Java or C# thing.

Answer (score 1):

Just like this:

```
// Note assume C++0x notation for simplicity since I don't know the type of the template
auto character = ourstack.top();

auto iter = std::find(visitable.begin(), visitable.end(), character);
if (iter != visitable.end())
    visitable.erase(iter);
```

returnTop does not exist in the stack class, but top does.

Alternatively if you want some generic (and rather flamboyant way) of doing it:

```
// Assume type of vector and stack are the same
template <class T>
void TryRemoveCharacter(std::vector<T>& visitable, const std::stack<T>& ourStack)
{
    // Note, could have passed a ref to the character directly, which IMHO makes more sense
    const T& ourChar = ourStack.top();

    visitable.erase(std::remove_if(visitable.begin(), visitable.end(), [&ourChar](const T& character)
    {
        // Note, this will not work http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/
        // says that std::find uses the operator== for comparisons but I doubt that
        // as compilers typically do not generate equal comparison operator.
        // See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217911/why-dont-c-compilers-define-operator-and-operator
        // It's best to either overload the operator== to do a true comparison or
        // add a comparison method and invoke it here.
        return ourChar == character;
    }));
}
```

Note: this alternative way may not be a good idea for an assignment as your teacher will probably find suspicious that you introduce advanced C++ features (C++0x) all of a sudden.
However for intellectual curiosity it could work ;)

Here's how you may use it:

```
TryRemoveCharacter(visitable, ourstack);
```